# Update Github repository with new files

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and github. If i have local files that I edited on my computer and would like to push changes to the same project which I have in my Github repository. What command can I use to push the changes and update my Github repository?

Comment: I would suggest you read through the Github documentation https://help.github.com/articles/good-resources-for-learning-git-and-github/

Answer (score 2):

If you are not yet familiar with Git, I'd recommend you start with the GitHub Desktop App (works on Windows and OSX) which will allow you to do these basic operations.

[https://desktop.github.com](https://desktop.github.com/)

[image: github desktop app]

Answer (score 1):

First stage your files:

```
git add <filename>
```

If you wish to stage everything and you are at the root of your Git repository directory do:

```
git add .
```

Next, create a commit of the content that you just staged:

```
git commit -m "my useful message"
```

Finally, push your commit(s) to GitHub:

```
git push
```

Go ahead and run these steps to get your stuff pushed, but you will absolutely need to go through a Git tutorial or two before being able to use Git at any level of efficiency: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/

Comment: I think the problem is i am not being able to integrate the repo to my current files. I tried: 
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo
then
git push -u origin master

Comment: @Sandes that comment doesn't really give enough information about the issue you are having...please run those commands and report back if you get errors

Comment: "git stash", "git pull --rebase", "git stash pop" before all of these ? And he should check configs for  email and user probably.

Comment: @Dzenly Yes, that's good advice if he is working on a repo with other people who may have updated master since he last cloned/pulled. But I think we need more info from him before taking him down the path of rebasing and such

Answer (score 0):

```
# Clone your Github repository.
git clone git@github.com:derekmahar/logback.git

# Add and commit files to your local repository.
cd logback
touch newfile
git add .
git commit --message "Added newfile."

# Push changes to your Github repository.
git push
```